# Where's the 2nd memory slot in a Toshiba Satellite 1900-603 laptop

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a Toshiba Satellite 1900-603 laptop that I'm trying to add memory to. It came with 512Mb RAM (which I was told consisted of 2x256Mb sticks) and after research I ordered two 512Mb sticks which arrived this morning.

The existing memory turned out to be on 1x512Mb stick and I replaced it with one of the new ones (which resulted in the computer now reporting it has 768Mb of RAM which is nice but puzzling).

Anyway, **my question is where is the second memory slot?** The one that was being used only takes 1 stick. There is a second slot in the same compartment (described as the memory module in the manual) but the second slot isn't wide enough to take the second stick nor does it have the 'notch' to show which way to install the memory.

Everything I've read from the manual to online states it has two memory slots so where is it? Any photos or videos showing the second slot would be particularly useful.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved!

After a lot of searching, I found this [walkthrough](http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-1905/remove-notebook-memory-1.htm) Although it's for a different model, physically it's identical to my Satellite 1900-603.

It turns out the second memory slot is under the keyboard - NOTHING I read before (including the manual) suggested this. Also, it turned out each 
slot originally came with 256Mb of memory installed which explains why, after I installed one 512Mb stick, Windows reported 768Mb of memory.

Anyway, after wrestling the plastic strip off and getting to the keyboard (Tip: try and shift the strip to the left a little first which releases the plastic 'teeth'), I've now installed the second stick and Windows shows 1Gb RAM is now installed.

Comment: +1 for coming back to self-answer the question. Not many does that.

Comment: Just to add that this model will take no more than 1gb RAM. So I would recommend running a linux OS if you want to see any speed. I've just rebuilt one which had just 256 "internal" RAM and 128 RAM in the user upgradeable slot. Seriously slow with XP Professional. Nicely built computer really, and ideal if you need the old fashioned connectors, floppy drive etc. 2 usb slots is a bit of a bummer though!