# What sort of RAM do I need for a Toshiba Satellite 310CDS?

Tags: memory, toshiba-laptop

I was thinking of upgrading my legacy notebook with some RAM.

This is a Toshiba Satellite 310CDS, and I'd like to put the maximum possible RAM module into it, to max-out the ram in that machine.

I do this only for hobbyist purposes, as this laptop is almost twelve years old, I don't do reasonable work on it any more. But since it's otherwise in perfect working order, I was thinking of maxing out the RAM, to run NetBSD more easily on it (surely not faster, though, since this laptop has only a 199MHz CPU)

OK, here comes the question:

What RAM module do I need (part number, etc) to max-out the RAM in that laptop?

I bought an SODIMM module one, and it fitted into the slot, but it wasn't recognized by the hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not find it overly easy to find RAM cheaply that is compatible with a laptop as old as that. IIRC those machines take EDO SODIMMS and have 32Mb built-in and you have one slot that you can add up to 128Mb in taking it up to 160Mb. If you can find compatible RAM at a reasonable price such a machine should boot lubuntu or puppy linux well enough and run fine for simple tasks (I'd not want to browse modern web sites in a modern browser on something like that, or try run OO.o on it, but for email, text/code editing, or just as a dumb terminal via VNC or similar the machine could be useful.

Comment: The laptop is running NetBSD for a few years now. I usually don't do much with it other than never shut it down, so the uptime goes up...

Comment: I tracked some sources down, but it's inconceivable how expensive the modules are! I wonder if I'll ever find cheap modules. the 64MB module goes for around 50 Euros, which is much more than I'm ready to pay...

Answer (score 0):

Sure go for it, revive the thing and put it to good use, I had an old IBM Thinkpad lying around, maxed out it's RAM and it's sitting here with me with Ubuntu working perfect :)

Comment: Yeah, problem is, I need the correct module. It doesn't seem to be that easy to find, though. I made some bad experiences with buying that from eBay, as I described in my question.

Comment: Well doing a bit of research it takes 96MB 144 Pin EDO SODIMM RAM, on a single slot. Looking around I can't seem to find 96MB sticks.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing with my Toshiba Satellite 1900-603 but had trouble locating the second memory slot so I [posted a question](https://superuser.com/questions/50354/wheres-the-2nd-memory-slot-in-a-toshiba-satellite-1900-603-laptop) and later found the answer. Perhaps my experience may help you. Good luck with it.